# Write a recursive function that takes two inputs, a base and an exponent, and returns the expected value of base ^ exponent

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I already have the answer to this question, which is

```
function pow(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return base * pow(base, exponent - 1);
}
```

What I'm not understand is the logic behind it. How does this work if we are returning 1? 1 does not equal the base to the power of the exponent

Comment: [Why does anything to the power of 0 equal 1?](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/qrwg3j/why_does_anything_to_the_power_of_0_equal_1/)

Comment: Sounds like question for https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: also, a shorter way to do that: `base ** exponent`

Answer (score -1):

The keyword is recursive. Try writing down on paper every call of the function. You are returning 1 only in case when the exponent is 0. You are multiplying the result of the function every time you call the function. For example, let's have pow(10,2)
The result would be 10x10x1